# .NET OleDbDataAdapter .Fill throws ullPointerException

Tags: vb.net, nullpointerexception, fill, oledbdataadapter

In my app, I use OleDbDataAdapter's & access data thru it to datasets. The code is :

```
        Dim id As Integer
    Try
        typeSql = "SELECT DOCHDR.dochdr_lDocId, TXNTYP.txntyp_cDocTypCat FROM TXNTYP INNER JOIN DOCHDR ON TXNTYP.txntyp_sDocTyp = DOCHDR.dochdr_sDocType WHERE ((DOCHDR.dochdr_lDocId)=395920);"
        typeAdap = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(typeSql, connStr)
        typeDs = New DataSet()
        type_adap.Fill(type_ds) ' THROWS ERROR

    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine("ERROR : " + ex.Message + " INNER " + ex.InnerException.ToString())
        Console.WriteLine("STACK = " + ex.StackTrace())
        Me.Close()
    End Try
```

I use other OleDbAdapter before this and other after this, but its this adap only that's throwing exception. Other all adaps/ds r filled the same way as above using different variables fo all.

```
MEssage : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

If I execute the query in DB, it shows 1 row

I can't makeout what is wrong here. Can anyone point out where am I going wrong ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    Dim id As Integer
Try
    typeSql = "SELECT DOCHDR.dochdr_lDocId, TXNTYP.txntyp_cDocTypCat FROM TXNTYP INNER JOIN DOCHDR ON TXNTYP.txntyp_sDocTyp = DOCHDR.dochdr_sDocType WHERE ((DOCHDR.dochdr_lDocId)=395920);"
    typeAdap = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(typeSql, connStr)
    typeDs = New DataSet()
    typeAdap.Fill(typeDs) ' THROWS ERROR

Catch ex As Exception
    Console.WriteLine("ERROR : " + ex.Message + " INNER " + ex.InnerException.ToString())
    Console.WriteLine("STACK = " + ex.StackTrace())
    Me.Close()
End Try
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are using the wrong `DataSet`:

```
type_adap.Fill(type_ds)
```

should be

```
typeAdap.Fill(typeDs)
```

since you are calling `typeDs = New DataSet()` the line before.

Comment: my type_adap should also be typeAdap. Thanks a lot.